# Text alignment with CheckBox

Tags: dart, flutter

I've the below code to display a text with check box, I need the text to be at the maximum left, and the check box to be at the maximum right, I got the checkbox correctly, but the text had been aligned to the side ot it as shown in the picture, I expect the result to show a wide gap between them!

```
  var _valueC = false;
  void onChecked(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _valueC = value;
      print('value: $value');
    });
  }

new Card(
  child: new Container(
    // height: 100.0,
    child: new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text("Agree"),
        new Checkbox(value: _valueC,
            onChanged: onChecked,
            ),
       ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

I've the below case that work perfectly with me with Switch and its text using Kotlin:

```
class Switchy : RelativeLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {
        val colorOn = -0xcdc1ba

        val trackStates = ColorStateList(
                arrayOf(intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked), intArrayOf()),
                intArrayOf(Color.LTGRAY, colorOn)
        )

        this.apply {
            layoutParams = android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

            addView(Switch(context).apply {
                    background =  ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.card)
                    text = "active or not is it  ?"
                    isChecked = true
                    showText = true
                    textOn = "Active"
                    textOff = "Not Active"
                    trackTintList = trackStates
                    thumbTintList = trackStates
                }, LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```

instead of

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
```